# T-SQL Removing numbers from the end of the email address

Tags: t-sql, email, trim

Right, I have some 21000 records where email addresses have numbers at the end ( . + 15 digit long number, example: xyz@gmail.com.201211200200027)

Now, the best solution I can think of is this:

```
Update TABLE
set EmailAddress = (
select substring (EmailAddress, 1, (len(EmailAddress) - 16))
from TABLE)
Where ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(Emailaddress, 15)) = 1
```

Above code doesn't work (*I am no T-SQL expert so forgive me if this code looks stupid*)

If I tell that code a specific email address then it works. Something like this:

```
Update TABLE
set EmailAddress = (
select substring (EmailAddress, 1, (len(EmailAddress) - 16))
from TABLE)
Where ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(Emailaddress, 15)) = 1
and Emailaddress is 'xyz@gmail.com.201211200200027'
```

So, How do I update these email addresses and remove last 16 characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET EmailAddress = LEFT(EmailAddress, LEN(EmailAddress) - 16 )
WHERE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', RIGHT(EmailAddress, 15)) = 0 AND LEN(EmailAddress) > 16
```

Comment: PATINDEX('[^0-9]%' --> you mean PATINDEX('%[^0-9]'? because my numbers are at the end of the email address

Comment: thanks Kaf, it worked like a charm. All I have to do now is flag this rows and update them. Many many thanks again. :D